# SharePoint 2010 subsites under logical segment

Tags: navigation

I am developing a intranet portal where we have logically segmented our subsites into two units. i.e BUSINESS and SERVICES.

The above units are mere logical representation nothing else. But the URL should be like

### Business

http://myportal/Business/SalesDistribution
http://myportal/Business/Marketing

### Services

http://myportal/Services/HR (main HR site for general users to access doc libraries)
http://myportal/Services/HR/StaffLoans  (reserved for HR loans employees team site)
http://myportal/Services/HR/StaffInsurance (reserved for HR Insurance employees team site)

But I dont want users to just type http://myportal/Business and reach there as this is not going to be the display page anyway as this is logical segmentation. No I have no clue how to create subsites like SalesDistribution, Marketing under logial segment "Business" and HR, StaffLoans and StaffInsurance under "Services" ..do i need to create Business and Services as subsite first and then create further subsites underneath or I can achieve the same urls without physically creating logical segments?

How would I handle this plz guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is to create two sub sites directly under the site collection. Then create further subsites under them. When user types something like http://myportal/Business, you can display a landing page for a business and that would be the default page for site created at http://myportal/Business. The landing page can include links to sites under it. You may also stop inheriting permissions at this level and give access to specific set of users.

Comment: Ahsish thank you for guiding me in right direction 1 last thing i want u to guide me also. I just stopped inheritance at "Services" level so it can't carry home level permissions & also "HR" level now the existing groups with set of permissions like "Approvers" "Designer" "Home Members" "Home Owners" etc Should I remove these group after stopping inheritance except for "Style Resource Readers" & "System Account" & create new group "Services Allowed Users" & include my name only as I am the only site collection admin & set the permissions for "HR" with default 9 Home groups?

Comment: I've sorted this by myself. No need of further comments..thanks anyway